# "Intelligence" (in the espionage sense) - first use?

Tags: etymology

Does anyone have an idea of when the word "intelligence" was first used, in the context of espionage? Was it used in this context in (for instance) the 18th century?

Comment: Oooh good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=&search=intelligencer&searchmode=none), the usage seems to pre-date the 1580s (assuming the agent noun came after the mass noun with the corresponding sense):

> intelligencer (n.)
>
> 1580s, "spy, informant," agent noun from *intelligence*.
>
> Meaning "bringer of news" is from 1630s; as a newspaper name from
>   1640s.

Indeed, Etymonline actually gives the 1580s as the time the 'military intelligence' sense originated. I'd assumed it didn't, as this now becomes general reference.

Comment: But OP isn't asking about the *person*, the *spy*, but the *information gathered* via espionage: the mass noun (aka the [G2](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=439411)). Any clues as to when that sense evolved?

Comment: Read more carefully.

Comment: I can only read carefully after you write carefully, Edwin. You changed your answer *after* I made my comment (which, I suppose, is a good thing: that's what comments on answers are supposed to encourage you to do!).

Comment: I added the parenthetical explanation for those not making the possible deduction '...  the agent noun came after the mass noun with the corresponding sense' (which is an assumption, but I believe a fair one). I'd assumed that OP had checked Etymonline for 'intelligence'. Wrongly.

Comment: Thanks. I had not heard of Etymonline until now. Appreciate it!